# Mount multiple shares with a single mount command

Tags: 14.04, mount

If I have in my fstab 10 shares/mountpoints, is it possible to run only a single mount command to mount them all at the same time just to avoid authenticating myself 10 times? I tried something like

```
sudo mount /mnt/share1, /mnt/share2, ...
```

etc but with no luck. Authentication is the same (same username, same password) for all the shares I am trying to mount.

Thanks

Comment: I think it depends on what is asking for authentication: If your computer, it should be OK, if other computers (servers), maybe more difficult unless you can use keys for authentication (possible (and recommended) with `ssh`).

Comment: You'll need to give more details about what you're mounting and how you authenticate, is the authentication different for every share. It would also be useful to define what constitutes insecure. For instance, when mounting Samba shares it's possible to use a credential file but this is a plain text file on your filesystem containing your username and password. Without this information I think your question won't get answered and is likely to be closed.

Comment: `sudo mount -a` will mount all not-mounted mountpoints in /etc/fstab, would that do it for you ?

Answer (score 3):

You can write a script which takes input for the username and password and applies it to each mount required. The script will need to be run with root level privileges. This also assumes that the mounts are all Samba shares. You'd need to tweak the script to include each of your mount points. With this script you will have to define all of your mount options rather than rely on those in `fstab`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter username for mounts:"
read mount_user
[[ -z "mount_user" ]] && echo "Username empty, exiting" && exit

echo "Enter password for mounts:"
read -s mount_pass
[[ -z "mount_pass" ]] && echo "Password empty, exiting" && exit

# Mount first share
mount -t cifs //server1/share1 /mnt/share1 -o username="$mount_user",password="$mount_pass"
# Mount second share
mount ...
```

Save this script as something like `/home/user/mountall`, and execute it with `sudo /home/user/mountall`.

This does load your password into memory in plain, and into a variable in the script's running process. Whether that is considered insecure in your environment is a question for your security team.

Comment: thanks, trying it now. Is it [[ -z "mount_user" ]] or [[ -z "mount_pass" ]] the second appearance?

Comment: Not working. Sorry ...

Comment: @pebox11 edited to correct errors and say to run the whole script with sudo. It does assume your shares are all Samba shares. Let me know if they're not and I'll edit again.

Comment: Yes all samba. Not my fault if not working to deserve a negative vote. But I guess that's the world! Thanks anyway ...

Comment: How would something like this work if I don't know all the share names? For example, given an IP address, I'd want my system to mount _all_ shares available. Is there a way to simply mount all available shares?

Answer (score 2):

Command you looking for is probably this:

```
sudo mount -a
```

I'm not sure how the authentication would work with it but give it a try. 
If it doesn't work you can always edit your fstab entry in this way:

```
//servername/sharename  /media/windowsshare  cifs  username=msusername,password=mspassword,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0
```

Comment: Nope this isn't it, tried that already. Not working

Comment: Have you tried adding username and password to fstab as I have just edited into the answer ?

Comment: Not permitted from regulations to store credentials on fstab. Not secure.

Comment: you can always store the credentals in a file under root directory and point fstab to that ?

Comment: Still not secure. Credentials are not supposed to exist in a production environment.

Answer (score 2):

Put your `mount` commands in a `bash` script, and `sudo` that script.

```
#!/bin/bash
mount .....
mount .....
mount .....
exit 0
```

Comment: Nope, tried that just now and it is not working. For each mount it asks for your credentials, even if you are the same user. So imagine if you have 20 different folders to mount you will have to authenticate 20 times and if the password is complex then don't even think about it.